# rails server works... but cannot generate scaffold

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sql-server

I ran my rails app correctly with `rails s -e production`, but when I run `rails generate scaffold Campaign title:string owner:string` I get

```
/Users/myhome/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/client.rb:44:in `connect': Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

Why is it so ? apache is correctly running since the app is running

Comment: What about MySQL server? Is it running on your machine?

Comment: @MarekLipka yes sure ! that's the weird part

Comment: Do you specify `socket` in your `database.yml` explicitly?

Comment: @MarekLipka yes, in my ./config/database.yml, I have socket: /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock in the production section

Comment: What if you get rid of this line?

Comment: @MarekLipka the server doesn't start if so

Comment: @MarekLipka shoud I alias /tmp/mysql.sock

Comment: Try to change so it points to your real `mysql` socket.

Comment: @MarekLipka in fact I have already alias mysql="/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql", it should be fine no ?

Comment: Don't know. Give it a try.

Comment: you might want to update your adapter to `mysql2` if it is not already.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have specified the socket `only` in production section in `database.yml`.

When you do `rails generate..` it will be run in `development` environment. So it is not able to connect to mysql database. Also while you are developing, there is no need to run the app in `production` mode. You can just use `rails s` to run it in development mode.

On a side note, on the production server, you will have to specify the production environment like this

`RAILS_ENV=production rails generate ..`